# Morphia - Merging a complex query with a complex criteria

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am converting filters from the client to a QueryImpl using the setQueryObject method.
When I try to add another complex criteria to that query my original query is moved to a field named baseQuery and the new criteria is the query field.
When the query is executed only the new criteria is used and the baseQuery is not used.
It only happens when the client query is formatted like this: { "$or" : [{ "field1" : { "$regex" : "value1", "$options" : "i"}},...]}
and the new criteria is formatted in the same way(meaning an $or operation).
It seems that when I try to merge 2 $or queries it happens but when I merge $or with $and it concatenates the queries properly.
Am I using it wrong or is it a genuine bug?
Edit:
Code:

```
public static List<Entity> getData(client.Query query) {
QueryImpl<Entity> finalQuery = Morphia.realAccess().extractFromQuery(Entity.class,query);
finalQuery.and(finalQuery.or(finalQuery.criteria("field").equal(false), finalQuery.criteria("field").doesNotExist()));
return finalQuery.asList();
}

public <E> QueryImpl<E> extractFromQuery(Class<E> clazz, client.Query query) {
    QueryImpl<E> result = new QueryImpl<E>(clazz,this.db.getCollection(clazz),this.db);
result.setQueryObject(query.getFiltersAsDBObject);
return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant morphia code to the post ?

Comment: Sure, will be up in a few minuets

Answer (score 0):

`QueryImpl` and `setQueryObject()` are internal constructs.  You really shouldn't be using them as they may change or go away without warning.  You should be using the public query builder API to build up your query document.

Comment: I have tried to use the public Query API but didn't find a way to convert a dbobject query to a Morphia query without the setQueryObjext method. Do you know a way of converting the dbobject to a query or a cirteria? How should I go about solving it ?

Comment: You wouldn't use a `DBObject` to build the query.  You'd use the Morphia API directly.

Comment: I am using the play framework. I get the query from the client side as a DBObject. How can i use the morphia API with it?

Comment: What client side is giving you a `DBObject`?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: The object im getting in the server is a custom query that extracted to a DBObject

Comment: I would also like to see an example of the morphia API you talk about :) if you have one i would like a link

Comment: They `Query` API can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/query/Query.html).  The top of the API is [here](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/)

Comment: We use play framework therefore the filter object from the client side is passed to the server side with the definitions of the routs file, when I pass a filter we use a custom query class which implements the play frameworks bindable class, i receive the object filter from the client as our custom query class, I saw that there was a objectToQuery method so I implemented a convertor from our query to a dbobject.
Where should I change the code? I have to use a query binder for play and I want to convert it to Morphia Query

Comment: Hey @evanchooly ,  I haven't heard from you about this since your last comment, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, It seems to be working when I do this:
finalQuery.and();
finalQuery.and(finalQuery.or(finalQuery.criteria("field").equal(false), finalQuery.criteria("field").doesNotExist()));
It is kind of ugly and would love to hear if someone have a different approach, but the only way I was able to find to convert the data from the client side which is a DBObject is to use the setQueryObject() of QueryImpl.